# std::to_chars compile but not linking on MacOS / clang

Tags: c++, macos, clang++, llvm-clang, undefined-symbol

I have problem compiling a project under MacOS with clang.

I did "pinpoint" the problem inside `charconv` header:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::array<char, 64> buffer;

    auto[p, ec] = std::to_chars(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 123);

    if (ec != std::errc() )
        std::cout << "error" << '\n';

    std::cout << (const char *) buffer.data() << '\n';
}
```

Here is how I am compiling it.

```
Nikolays-MacBook-Air:~ nmmm$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Nikolays-MacBook-Air:~ nmmm$ clang -std=c++17 x.cc -lstdc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__itoa::__u32toa(unsigned int, char*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__itoa::__traits_base<unsigned int, void>::__convert(unsigned int, char*) in x-9b1746.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Nikolays-MacBook-Air:~ nmmm$
```

Any help will be appreciated.

## update

I tried clang++, but it gives me same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<charconv>` header contains declarations and uses of `std::__1::__itoa::__u32toa`, a function which is not defined in that header. The function is defined in `libc++.dylib`. **However**, Apple does not ship `libc++.dylib` with the same frequency as it ships headers; and, possibly more important, [libc++ failed to include the new symbol in its "abilist" for Apple until 2018-09-23](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52396), even though [the header change landed on 2018-08-01](https://reviews.llvm.org/D41458). So there was a period of about 53 days where (this aspect of) libc++ just didn't work on OSX. Maybe Apple picked it up and shipped it during that period.

One way to make your code work is to build libc++ yourself. [Instructions here, as of late 2019.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/11/09/llvm-from-scratch/)

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 test.cc $ROOT/llvm-project/build/lib/libc++.dylib \
    -Wl,-rpath,$ROOT/llvm-project/build/lib
$ ./a.out
123
```

Some commenters on your question are suggesting that you could make your code work by using GNU libstdc++ instead of LLVM libc++. That's vaguely true, but I suspect that building libstdc++ for OSX will be even harder than building libc++ for OSX. (And the latter is not *simple!*) I am not aware of any way to install libstdc++ on OSX. There is `brew install gcc@8`, but I bet GCC 8 didn't have `<charconv>` either.

As of early 2020, *no* vendor ([except just recently Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4P_kbF0EbZM)) provides a full implementation of `<charconv>` — the floating-point `to_chars` and `from_chars` turn out to be difficult, so most vendors don't provide them. ("Why didn't they just copy an existing implementation?" Well, it turns out that `<charconv>` was standardized as part of C++17 before any implementation existed. Nobody guessed that it would be *difficult!*)

Comment: Do you know when is expected Apple to provide library with correct implementation for integers only? I mean when we might expect it?

Comment: I had the same issue with clang-7, upgrade to clang-8 solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping this code into your project will allow the use of to_chars (but not `from_chars`) with the stock libc++ on older versions of Mac OS — no need to build the standard library yourself.  I don't remember where I got this code or if I wrote it myself...  Essentially it's a correct implementation of the functions Apple forgot to add to the ABI.

**Macros to enable this based on deployment target are left as an exercise for the reader.**  This code won't compile/link properly against a deployment target of 10.15 or higher, or on Apple Silicon.

```cpp
// Extra code to enable std::to_chars / from_chars
static inline void reverseString(char *begin, char *end)
{
    --end;
    while (begin < end) {std::swap(*begin, *end); ++begin; --end;}
}

namespace std::__itoa {
_LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS char* __u64toa(uint64_t __value, char* __buffer)
{
    char *start = __buffer;
    do
    {
        *(__buffer++) = '0' + (__value%10);
        __value /= 10;
    }
    while (__value);
    
    reverseString(start, __buffer);
    
    //*__buffer = '\0';
    return __buffer;
}
_LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS char* __u32toa(uint32_t __value, char* __buffer)
{
    char *start = __buffer;
    do
    {
        *(__buffer++) = '0' + (__value%10);
        __value /= 10;
    }
    while (__value);
    
    reverseString(start, __buffer);
    
    //*__buffer = '\0';
    return __buffer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nice long answer to this, to then check and see that it works for me (clang 9.0.0 on linux). You compile with `clang` and not `clang++`. The long answer below:

Clang's libc++ has not fully implemented the "Elementary string conversions, revision 5 " (as in `to_chars` and `from_chars`) for a long time and some parts are still outstanding, see [here](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html). But I think yours should work, so maybe you should update your library.

For usage of `to_chars` please consider, that it explicitly adds *no* `\0` at the end of the string. Therefore you cannot just use `std::cout << (const char *) buffer.data();`. You have to use the pointer (named `p` in your code) to mark the end of your string. Either by inserting a `\0`, by generating a `std::string_view sv(buffer.data(), static_cast<size_t>(p-buffer.data());`, using `std::copy(buffer.begin(), p, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));` or another of far too many ways.

Comment: I know about \0, but example worked on gcc. Any easy way to update the library on MacOS ?

Comment: You did not read my answer: You use the wrong compiler. Type `clang++` not `clang`.

Comment: clang++ have absolutely the same output.

Comment: I use not apple system and it would be also just googling for me to find out what to do. Is there are reason to not use g++ if it works there? Why are you specifying the standard library and not using the default?

Comment: `clang++ -std=c++17 x.cc -lstdc++`

isn't this correct way for compiling c++17 on unix, linux and macos? without `-lstdc++` iostream will not work.

Comment: On my system I call `clang++ -std=c++17 x.cc`. Looking at the manpage the intended way to specify the stdlib is `-stdlib=<library>`, where possible values for library are `libc++` and `libstdc++`. For me only the later works since it seems i dont have libc++ installed. But if it works with gcc, it should also work with clang since they can use the same standardlibrary (it's only code). Maybe you want to find out which one gcc uses.