# Undefined symbol std::from_chars(...)

Tags: c++, linux, c++17

When attempting to run a shared library I've built I am hitting the error when trying to load the shared library (within Linux) `undefined symbol: _ZSt10from_charsPKcS0_ReSt12chars_format`. Performing `nm --unmangle` shows that the lines that are causing an issue are:

```cpp
U std::from_chars(char const*, char const*, double&, std::chars_format)
U std::from_chars(char const*, char const*, long double&, std::chars_format)
U std::from_chars(char const*, char const*, float&, std::chars_format)
```

After trying to figure this out, as it is quite weird coming from the standard library, is that it is a known and common issue. Some similar threads are:

- [std::to_chars compile but not linking on MacOS / clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923623/stdto-chars-compile-but-not-linking-on-macos-clang)
- [Compile error when calling std::from_chars with a double in libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669008/compile-error-when-calling-stdfrom-chars-with-a-double-in-libc)

Looking at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support also confirms this with the line relating to this problem being: `P2291R3`.

I think this is coming from the `libpqxx` library I have included as it is not in any of my code therefore, my question:

*Is there any method out there to deal with this?*

Could I create a definition for this just to overload it? Are this going to be implemented soon? Or do I have to only change the `libpqxx` library? At least the version.

- Linux: Ubuntu 20.04
- Compiler: G++-10

### Update

From one of the comments below pointed out that:

1. Was not looking at the wrong list
2. Upgrading to the most up to date g++11 solved this issue

Comment: `attempting to run a shared library` what do you mean? Please post the command line use to compile your program and the ones that produce that error.

Comment: Does "G++-10" support that feature of the C++ standard library?

Comment: @ichramm I'm also using the `dylib` library to handle loading and it just uses the `open()` function from linux headers: `m_handle = open((final_path + final_name).c_str());`

Comment: @NicolBolas Looking at the compiler support, no compiler support it but given this I dont know why it is in as an option?

Comment: @Adriano: "*Looking at the compiler support, no compiler support it*" [That's untrue.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17) Clang 's Libc++ doesn't but more recent versions of VS and GCC do.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hmmm seems like I was looking at the wrong list. Looks like I also have to update to G++11 in order for this to work as G++8 does not have the FP support

Comment: Probably your build process is wrong. Invoking `gcc` is not same thing as invoking `g++`. The first one do not link C++ standard library implicitly - when this happens it explains your error. So please provide description of your build process.

Comment: Lack of `P2291R3` will lead to compile time issue not linking issue.

Comment: Im running an example just fine on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/c9Y3fh83P